# jquery validate showing previous errors for valid field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Just started using jquery validate and i'm getting multiple errors for fields that were invalid. I moved the error container and I can see all errors are still there after the field is corrected. I end up with a bunch of errors stacked on top of each other. I would like to see "current" errors.

You can see what I mean here: http://opiemedia.com/dev/lo/sv/varB/

This is what im using form validation

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#evalFrm").validate({

   rules: {
     name: {
       required: true,
       minlength: 2,
     },
     company: {
       minlength: 2,
     },
     email: {
       required: true,
       email: true,
     },
     phone: {
       required:true,
       minlength: 7,
     }
   },
   errorLabelContainer: "#evalErr",
   errorClass: "error label label-warning"
  });
 });
```

This is the HTML

```
<div class="span8 well" style="margin-left:0;">
      <form id="evalFrm action="#" method="post" class="evalFrm" name="evalFrm">
        <input name="oid" type="hidden" value="00D400000008j4N" />
        <input name="retURL" type="hidden" value="#" />
        <input class="span6" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" /> 
        <input class="span6" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Company" type="text" />
        <input class="span6" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" /> 
        <input class="span6" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" type="tel" /> 
        <button class="btn btn-success span6 offset3" type="submit"onclick="_kmq.push(['record', 'Request Info Form Submission']);">Evaluate </button>
            </form>
            <div id="evalErr"></div>
          </div>
```

Thanks for taking the time to help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have come across a bug in the library, the problem is you have 3 classes in the `errorClass` propery, if you pass 2 classes it works fine.

The bug is in the following line in the `errors()` method

```
var errorClass = this.settings.errorClass.replace(" ", ".");
```

it replaces only one `<space>` with `.` where as it should have replaces all instances.

Demo: [Two classes works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zqm8G/3/)
Demo: [Three classes does not work](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zqm8G/4/)

Fix:
If you are using a local copy of the validator.js file then you can fix it by changing the line to

```
var errorClass = this.settings.errorClass.replace(/\s/g, ".");
```

*Note: I'll try to submit a patch later in the day*

Comment: Thank you! I actually didnt need the first .error class so I just left label and label-warning.